# Is "Sign in with Apple" compulsory as iOS 13 is released

Tags: ios, app-store, apple-id

As per the AppStore review guidelines, now apps which are offering sign in with other social services also need the option of apple sign in.

> 4.8 Sign in with Apple Apps that exclusively use a third-party or social login service (such as Facebook Login, Google Sign-In, Sign in
>   with Twitter, Sign In with LinkedIn, Login with Amazon, or WeChat
>   Login) to set up or authenticate the user’s primary account with the
>   app must also offer Sign in with Apple as an equivalent option. A
>   user’s primary account is the account they establish with your app for
>   the purposes of identifying themselves, signing in, and accessing your
>   features and associated services.

We are planning to upload a new app with social sign-in options today which doesn't support login with apple id yet. So anyone faced any issues with review recently.

Comment: Do you also have a non-third-party login option? Or do you "exclusively use a third-party or social login service" ?

Comment: @Thilo yes we have non-third party login option as well, we have our own server setup, where user can register and login.

Comment: @Thilo got it so as you are saying, as we are offering non-third party option as well, so it should be fine right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

******Update******

9th April 2020 Apple sent email to all developers and informed about change in guidelines,

> Please note that all apps that authenticate or set up user accounts
>   must support Sign in with Apple if required by guideline 4.8 of the
>   App Store Review Guidelines. New apps must follow guideline 4.8 and
>   Human Interface Guidelines on Sign in with Apple **starting April 30,
>   2020. App updates must follow these guidelines starting June 30, 2020**.

Ref: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#sign-in-with-apple

[image]

Comment: App got rejected, even though there were both options available

Comment: @Emil is your app having login using your own server option, then it should be approved for e.g. Example app is having login option using example.com api, it should be approved, if its available you can add comment in the review section and resubmit for the review.

Comment: they've ignored my statement. Also I'm not the only one with this issue
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59225567/apple-rejection-for-third-party-sign-up

Comment: My App updated on June 5th so its got approved. Now i am giving one more update got rejected! don't know what exact reason.

Comment: @User558 this policy is in effect from 30th June 2020 now for the updates as well, so we all need to update existing apps with the apple sign in now.

Answer (score 1):

I raise a question around the term "exclusively" as this could suggest that if you ONLY use social local. So if I put a lawyer hat on, it may be appropriate to submit if you are using email/phone/username as well as third party auth.

Just my 2p on the matter!?

Answer (score 0):

New apps which are using other third-party social login(e.g. Facebook, Google, LinkedIn, Twitter) must provide **Sign-In With Apple** from September 2019.

Existing apps and app updates must follow them by April 2020.

> We’ve updated the App Store Review Guidelines to provide criteria for
>   when apps are required to use Sign in with Apple. Starting today, new
>   apps submitted to the App Store must follow these guidelines. Existing
>   apps and app updates must follow them by April 2020. We’ve also
>   provided new guidelines for using Sign in with Apple on the web and
>   other platforms.

New Guidelines for SignIn With Apple: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=09122019b

> **4.8 Sign in with Apple**
>
> Apps that exclusively use a third-party or social login service (such
>   as Facebook Login, Google Sign-In, Sign in with Twitter, Sign In with
>   LinkedIn, Login with Amazon, or WeChat Login) to set up or
>   authenticate the user’s primary account with the app must also offer
>   Sign in with Apple as an equivalent option.
>
> A user’s primary account is the account they establish with your app
>   for the purposes of identifying themselves, signing in, and accessing
>   your features and associated services.
>
> **Sign in with Apple is not required if:**
>
> -> Your app exclusively uses your company’s own account setup and sign-in systems.
>
> -> Your app is an education, enterprise, or business app that requires the user to sign in with an existing education or enterprise account.
>
> -> Your app uses a government or industry-backed citizen identification system or electronic ID to authenticate users.
>
> -> Your app is a client for a specific third-party service and users are required to sign in to their mail, social media, or other
>   third-party account directly to access their content.

Here is the link of AppStore Review Guidelines:- [SignIn With Apple](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#sign-in-with-apple)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm still not sure as, Apple is saying this rule is applicable for the apps that "exclusively using third-party logins".

one of the other answer on SO, he is saying his app is rejected and approved again https://stackoverflow.com/a/59382162/1228669

Anyways its better to explore sign in with apple approach and add to the apps.

Comment: @prasad Thanks for your consideration. The scenario is different for that user. Kindly read his explanation. His app does not come under the case where he needs to provide SignIn with Apple. His app does NOT EXCLUSIVELY use a third-part or social login service.

Answer (score -1):

March 4, 2020, Apple released a statement that “All new apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must follow these guidelines [Resources and Sign-in Guidelines] by April 30 (extended to June) 2020.”

The guidelines now require a “Sign in with Apple” (SIWA) button for apps with third-party sign-in options (Facebook, Google, Twitter, etc.).

This development would seem pretty straightforward — but it is not without its nuances.

[In this article](https://medium.com/@Alconost/sign-in-with-apple-announced-c5faaec61f46) we've highlighted and questioned some related issues:

1. Can you simply opt-out of using “Sign in with Apple”?
2. Some insights on user data
3. Design-related concerns

Hope, it helped. You're welcome to post your arguments and comments!