# Apple Rejection For Third Party Sign Up

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Apple Review team rejected the Application with the reason

**"We noticed that your app uses a third-party login service but does not offer Sign in with Apple.
"**

Even Application have normal Signup process as well with Email and Password.

Is it Mandatory to have Apple Signin in iOS 13 apps ?

Comment: Got Approval by Apple review team, After integration Apple Sign In functionality. Thanks

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please mark it as the accepted answer to help other users in the future! https://stackoverflow.com/a/59225838/7461562

Answer (score 15):

**Update 3 (March 04, 2020)**

The [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#sign-in-with-apple) have been updated to cover cases that use both third party and their own sign in services. Those apps are now required to offer Sign in with Apple. Therefore I'll be updating my apps to support Sign in with Apple and I recommend you do the same if you fall into this category.

**Original Answer:**

So my app just got rejected for the exact same reason. My app offers regular email and password authentication as well as Facebook and Google login. Here are a few interesting things that I found while reading the App Store Review Guidelines.

**1. It says:**

> Apps that **exclusively** use a third-party or social login service (such as Facebook Login, Google Sign-In, Sign in with Twitter, Sign In with LinkedIn, Login with Amazon, or WeChat Login) to set up or authenticate the user’s primary account with the app must also offer Sign in with Apple as an equivalent option.

But my app does NOT EXCLUSIVELY use a third-part or social login service. It also uses our own email/ password method. In fact the email and password method is on top and thus assumed to be the main method of authentication. So I feel like this rule does not apply to my app.

**2. It also says:**

> **Sign in with Apple is not required if**:
>
> Your app **exclusively** uses your company’s own account setup and sign-in systems...

**3. The first 2 rules don't cover my app's case.**

My app does NOT EXCLUSIVELY use third-party login services and does NOT EXCLUSIVELY use our own method. It uses both. So it's neither required to implement the Sign in with Apple nor exempt from implementing it.

**4. I submitted 2 apps for review in the same day with the exact same authentication methods and only one of them got rejected.**

Yesterday I submitted 2 apps for review that are part of the same project and have the exact same authentication methods with the exact same auth screen design. They both got in review at the same time. The first one got approved and the second one got rejected for not implementing Sign in with Apple. Funny, right?

So unless they update the Review Guidelines to cover a case where you use both methods of authentication I believe we are not violating any rule. I'm trying to argue with the review team that my rejected app does not violate the App Store Review Guidelines and they should not have rejected it.

I'll update my answer when this get's resolved but till then it might actually help if others who face the same issue point this out to the review team. We'll either win our case and get our apps approved or they'll update their Review Guidelines to cover our case. Either way it'll be helpful for others in the future.

**Update 1**

Apple kinda understood that this is not right and my app's status changed from Binary Rejected to In Review. Now I'm waiting to see what they decide.

**Update 2**

After about 40 hours of being "In Review" my app finally got approved and is now "Ready for Sale". I can't believe it, but it finally feels like someone listened and understood the arguments that I made.

Comment: Hey, my app also got rejected, even though it's for a school ("app for education")  and we use Google G Suite to manage accounts ("exclusively uses your company's own account setup and sign-in systems"), and we still got rejected. Our appeal failed, and they said that was "final" -- any advice? Also, please update when you get approved, I would like to have some frame of reference for other devs out there.

Comment: Hi @LeviLesches. I just updated my answer. My app got approved.

Comment: Congrats! They have yet to take my app out of "rejected", but now I'm optimistic

Comment: @MrStanev what you discussed with apple reviewer? I also want to approve my app.

Comment: @EktaPadaliya Basically I explained the things I wrote in this answer. Nothing else. I guess this got them thinking and they understood my points. But as you know apps are reviewed by different people so the person reviewing your app may decide that my arguments are irrelevant.

Comment: Did you get approve from Apple? @LeviLesches

Comment: Unfortunately not, they've been pretty firm on the rule, though they did make an appeal to the higher ups to make the rule more lenient, but that's a very long process. In the meantime, we're going to get a private distribution and won't be publishing to the app store

Comment: Thank you for posting your experience. Our apps also fit within this (deliberate?) gray area within Apple's App Store Review guidelines. Where we offer a regular username + password login, but also allow user's to login with Google and Facebook. So we're not 'exclusive' to either. Have you had any more issues getting your app approved since your last update?

Comment: @cwills I've only tried to publish one update (a minor bug fix), but they rejected it for a completely different reason - creating an account is not necessary to view most of the content according to them, so they asked me to make the sign up process optional (which my client refuses to do, so we just left it like that). Other than that I haven't published any updates.

Comment: Thanks for the information, this is really good info. I had the same experience. In my case Apple QA/Reviewers didn't speak Spanish and didn't see the button to login/sign up -.-

Comment: Apple has now updated
4.8 Sign in with Apple
Apps that use a third-party or social login service (such as Facebook Login, Google Sign-In, Sign in with Twitter, Sign In with LinkedIn, Login with Amazon, or WeChat Login) to set up or authenticate the user’s primary account with the app must also offer Sign in with Apple as an equivalent option. A user’s primary account is the account they establish with your app for the purposes of identifying themselves, signing in, and accessing your features and associated services.

Comment: Apple has removed the `Your app exclusively uses your company’s own account setup and sign-in systems` line so your app will no longer be accepted. You must always include Apple Sign In when you are using a third party login provider

Answer (score 6):

If you use any third-party sign-in feature, e.g. Facebook, Twitter, Google etc, you must now provide Apple Sign In as an additional option.

It's important to remember if you use solely a custom login system (i.e. email and password) then you do not need to include Apple Sign In.

> **4.8 Sign in with Apple**
>
> Apps that exclusively use a third-party or social login service (such as Facebook Login, Google Sign-In, Sign in with Twitter, Sign In with LinkedIn, Login with Amazon, or WeChat Login) to set up or authenticate the user’s primary account with the app must also offer Sign in with Apple as an equivalent option. A user’s primary account is the account they establish with your app for the purposes of identifying themselves, signing in, and accessing your features and associated services.
>
> **Sign in with Apple is not required if:**
>
> Your app exclusively uses your company’s own account setup and sign-in systems.
> Your app is an education, enterprise, or business app that requires the user to sign in with an existing education or enterprise account.
> Your app uses a government or industry-backed citizen identification system or electronic ID to authenticate users.
> Your app is a client for a specific third-party service and users are required to sign in to their mail, social media, or other third-party account directly to access their content.

Further reading can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

Comment: I made an app for a school that couldn't make it to the App Store before this new guideline was imposed -- we were rejected because we require the students' Google G Suite account and cannot use an anonymous email to access student data. I appealed, and they rejected again, commenting that the rejection was final. What can I do about this?

Comment: Nothing is the short answer. As many people have said before, it's entirely possible for you to resubmit the same build for review and it may go through but it's no guarantee. Does your app use solely G Suite?

Comment: We use the fact that they're logged in to their g suite account (managed by the school) as proof enough that they're logged in -- we'd really rather not Interface directly with the school servers. Also we may/may not add their Google drive or Google calendars to the app, so it may be required. We use Firebase for authentication, so using Google is really smooth here. But I'll try my luck at resubmitting, because they stopped responding to my questions for this build.

Comment: If you use Firebase for authentication, why don't you integrate it directly within the app and have your students authenticate using their username/password from Firebase?

Answer (score 5):

Bad news: the word "exclusively" has been removed from the guidelines early March.

> Apps that use a third-party or social login service (such as Facebook Login, Google Sign-In, Sign in with Twitter, Sign In with LinkedIn, Login with Amazon, or WeChat Login) to set up or authenticate the user’s primary account with the app must also offer Sign in with Apple as an equivalent option

Comment: Yeah now you have to have a reason like: Administrators of company domains may require Google sign-in for their employees to use your app. Our app gets rejected every time for this reason, and this has become a form letter we send in the appeal, they approve it every time. It's the truth for us at least, not lying to them.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, yes. New apps that use sign-in must provide sign-in with Apple as an option. Existing apps that use sign-in must provide sign-in with Apple by April 2020.

> We’ve updated the App Store Review Guidelines to provide criteria for
>   when apps are required to use Sign in with Apple. Starting today [Sept
>   12, 2019], new apps submitted to the App Store must follow these
>   guidelines.

(Source: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=09122019b)

**App Store Review Guidelines**

> 4.8 Sign in with Apple
>
> Apps that exclusively use a third-party or social login service (such
>   as Facebook Login, Google Sign-In, Sign in with Twitter, Sign In with
>   LinkedIn, Login with Amazon, or WeChat Login) to set up or
>   authenticate the user’s primary account with the app must also offer
>   Sign in with Apple as an equivalent option. A user’s primary account
>   is the account they establish with your app for the purposes of
>   identifying themselves, signing in, and accessing your features and
>   associated services.
>
> Sign in with Apple is not required if:
>
> · Your app exclusively uses your company’s own account setup and
>   sign-in systems.
>
> · Your app is an education, enterprise, or business app that requires
>   the user to sign in with an existing education or enterprise account.
>
> · Your app uses a government or industry-backed citizen identification
>   system or electronic ID to authenticate users.
>
> · Your app is a client for a specific third-party service and users
>   are required to sign in to their mail, social media, or other
>   third-party account directly to access their content.

(Source: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines)

Comment: Thanks, But i got the apple approval for the same app few days back, And now they are rejecting the Application with this reason.

Comment: The review process can be a bit hit and miss sometimes.

Comment: It is quite common to have rejections based on things that have been approved many times in your app or other people's apps. It's common to have rejections based on parts of that app that have nothing to do with the parts you changed for this release. This is neither unusual, nor an argument you can use to appeal the rejection.

Comment: What happen if I don't provide Apple Sign in in my existing app by April 2020?

Comment: @cloudy_weather, obviously, any new submission will get rejected.

Comment: I meant what's the impact on existing apps if they don't provide the apple sign in in time for April, are they going to be suspended from the store? or blocked?

Answer (score 2):

Today morning my app also got rejected because of the same reason but I was not using any third party sign up.

After rejection, I realised that in side menu under login button, I have 5 social media buttons for their respective social media page links so I replied to Resolution Center that I am using regular email based register and login. Also, I shared the screenshot of both screens (Login & Register). After 7-8 hours the status changed to 'In Review' and after next 10 minutes Apple approved and it goes live.