# App required(mandatory) Sign In With Apple or not?

Tags: ios, sign-in-with-apple

My app offers regular email and password authentication as well as Facebook and Google login.

**Apple guidelines say:**

> Apps that exclusively use a third-party or social login service (such
>   as Facebook Login, Google Sign-In, Sign in with Twitter, Sign In with
>   LinkedIn, Login with Amazon, or WeChat Login) to set up or
>   authenticate the user’s primary account with the app must also offer
>   Sign in with Apple as an equivalent option.

But my app does NOT EXCLUSIVELY use a third-part or social login service. It also uses our own email/ password method. In fact the email and password method is on top and thus assumed to be the main method of authentication. So I feel like this rule does not apply to my app.

**Apple guidelines also say:**

> Sign in with Apple is not required if: Your app exclusively uses your
>   company’s own account setup and sign-in systems...

My app does NOT EXCLUSIVELY use third-party login services and does NOT EXCLUSIVELY use our own method. It uses both.

So does my App required(mandatory) Sign In With Apple or not?

Comment: Since you already offer social sign in, why not offer Sign In With Apple anyway - It is a great user experience, no typing and gives the user control over sharing their email address.  Developing for iOS shouldn't be about doing the minimum.  It should be about delighting your users and giving them the experience they expect from the Apple ecosystem.

Comment: @miOS basically if your apps offer third-party login-register option then you have to provide "Sign In With Apple" also. otherwise don't required.

Comment: @Paulw11 is right. miOS if you need any help in implementation please let us know.

Comment: @Paulw11Client only want this feature if it is mandatory.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59225567/apple-rejection-for-third-party-sign-up?rq=1

Comment: One more thing shoved down the throat of the developer/user just because it's Apple and it's qUiRkY, SMH.

Comment: @Paulw11 Why not offer Sign In With Apple? Because Apple sign is a piece of sh.t because enables user to change name and surname to whatever + email can be hidden (and later in options forwarding mails from app to user can be turned off). That is why Apple Sign in is not widely used. We do not need fake/anonymous accounts.

Comment: How is that different to any other email service?  I can sign up for a new Gmail or Outlook.com address in a few minutes.  There is no validation of my real identity and I can delete that account or just stop checking it at any time.

Answer (score 2):

Apple updated the guidelines on March 4 to [make it mandatory](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) if you offer social login as an option.  Note the removal of the word 'exclusive':

> Apps that use a third-party or social login service (such as Facebook Login, Google Sign-In, Sign in with Twitter, Sign In with LinkedIn, Login with Amazon, or WeChat Login) to set up or authenticate the user’s primary account with the app must also offer Sign in with Apple as an equivalent option.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple answer..

If your app provides third-party login-register option (like Facebook, google, instagram, twitter, etc..) then "Sign In With Apple" **required** otherwise **don't required.**

Comment: they have mentioned, "exclusively use a third-party or social login service". In our case, it's both. So might not mandatory. The statements from guidelines are contradictory.

Comment: i think you have to integrate sign in with apple. if apple tester sees fb, g+ or any other  then they will ask for sign in apple also.